# Generating JSON schema from C# class

Tags: c#, json, jsonschema

Is there any way to programmatically generate a JSON schema from a C# class?

Something which we can do manually using http://www.jsonschema.net/

Comment: Have a log at this: http://csharp2json.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Nobody picked up that site doesn't generate schema from C#, but from JSON. And the previous comment's link is C# to JSON, not schema. This however is one way to do it online. https://dotnetfiddle.net/sjmS9Z

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Another option which supports generating JSON Schema v4 is [NJsonSchema](http://njsonschema.org):

```
var schema = JsonSchema.FromType<Person>();
var schemaJson = schema.ToJson();
```

The library can be installed via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NJsonSchema/).

**Update for NJsonSchema v9.4.3+:**

```
using NJsonSchema;

var schema = await JsonSchema.FromTypeAsync<Person>();
var schemaJson = schema.ToJson();
```

Answer (score 8):

This is supported in [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) via the [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/) NuGet package. Instructions on how to use it can be found in the [official documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GeneratingSchemas.htm), but I've also included a simple example below.

```cs
JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Person));
Console.WriteLine(schema.ToString());
//{
//  "type": "object",
//  "properties": {
//    "Name": {
//      "type": [ "string", "null" ]
//    },
//    "Age": { "type": "integer" }
//  },
//  "required": [ "Name", "Age" ]
//}
```

Comment: Please note that licensing may be a thing when using the newtonsoft json schema package

Comment: Good point, the licensing/pricing information can be found here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/store/jsonschema

Answer (score 1):

For those who land here from google searching for the reverse 
(generate the C# class from JSON) - I use those fine online tools:

JSON:
http://json2csharp.com/
(Source: http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/)

XML: 
http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/
(Source: https://github.com/msyoung/XmlToCSharp)

Comment: From reverse jsonclassgenerator tool is great. Another simple option is to use Edit->Paste Special-> Paste JSON as Classes in Visual Studio. This creates a class too! Quite handy sometimes.

Comment: @sandiejat: Nice to know. Wonder since which version of VS.

Comment: Seems like 2012.2 RC brought it. And we were busy doing it difficult way! :)
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc/

Answer (score 1):

```
JsonSchemaGenerator js = new JsonSchemaGenerator();
var schema = js.Generate(typeof(Person));
schema.Title = typeof(Person).Name;
using (StreamWriter fileWriter = File.CreateText(filePath))
{
      fileWriter.WriteLine(schema);
}
```

Comment: It not free, it has 10 time for hours