# Serialization - C# Data Types

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have an object that I wish to serialize into JSON, but instead of each property having its associated value, I'd rather have each property have its associated type.

For example, I have the following class:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public bool IsMarried { get; set; }
}
```

The resulting JSON I would like to have looks like this

```
{
    "Student:" {
       "Name": "String",
       "Age": "Int",
       "DateOfBirth": "DateTime",
       "IsMarried": "Boolean"
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can setup a `JsonSerializer` to serialize each property's `type` instead of its `value`?

Comment: Are you looking for a [json schema generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782982/generating-json-schema-from-c-sharp-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using information from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934487/custom-json-serialization-of-class) answer to build a custom `JsonSerializer`, you can modify the `WriteJson` method to specify the information that you want to write.

Building a custom `JsonSerializer` requires creating a new class and deriving it from `JsonSerializer`, then override any methods that you are interested in customizing.

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
        return;
    }

    var properties = value.GetType().GetProperties();

    writer.WriteStartObject();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        // Write the property name
        writer.WritePropertyName(property.Name);
        // Get the value of the property and get the type
        serializer.Serialize(writer, property.GetValue(value, null).GetType());
    }

    writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying [Ian H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5507624/ian-h)'s answer I was able to create a custom `JsonConverter` to handle writing property types to JSON.

```
public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type[] _types;

    public CustomConverter(params Type[] types)
    {
        _types = types;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
            return;
        }

        var properties = value.GetType().GetProperties();

        writer.WriteStartObject();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            // Write the property name
            writer.WritePropertyName(property.Name);
            // Get the property type name of the property
            serializer.Serialize(writer, property.PropertyType.Name);
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return _types.Any(t => t == objectType);
    }
}
```

Using another custom class of mine, witch each property being a string, upon trying to convert a fresh, new instance of the class every property value is `null`, so calling `property.GetValue(value, null).GetType()` throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Because of this I substituted that line of code with `property.PropertyType.Name`, which works perfectly!

Comment: Nice! Didn't know `PropertyName` existed until now, great job on finding out!

Comment: What are the `writer.WriteStartObject()` and `writer.WriteEndObject()` lines for?

Comment: AFAIK they write the indicators for the beginning `{` and the end `}` to the `JsonWriter`.